# ZFS logicalreferenced vs referenced

Tags: ubuntu, zfs, zfsonlinux

After sending a zvol from one pool to another I was alarmed to find that only half the data was "there" (according to `REFER`). Then I noticed on the sent snapshot that `referenced` is `302G` and `logicalreferenced` is `150G`. But after sending it to a new pool these two values match. I don't understand why this is, and if anything I thought `logicalreferenced` is supposed to be larger than `referenced`. The `302G` is espiecially confusing because the zvol was populated by sending a 150GB drive over iSCSI using `dd`.

```
tank/Win10Root         831G   747G   302G  -
tank/Win10Root@send  referenced            302G                   -
tank/Win10Root@send  logicalreferenced     150G                   -

# zfs send tank/Win10Root@send | zfs recv wd/Win10Root

wd/Win10Root           151G  6.24T   151G  -
wd/Win10Root@send  referenced            151G                   -
wd/Win10Root@send  logicalreferenced     150G                   -
```

EDIT: Posted `logicalused` (which is 0) instead of `logicalreferenced` on accident

These are all the properties for `tank/Win10Root`. The zvol was created with `zfs create -V 512G tank/Win10Root`.

```
@ubuntu1:~$ sudo zfs get all tank/Win10Root | sort
NAME            PROPERTY              VALUE                  SOURCE
tank/Win10Root  available             740G                   -
tank/Win10Root  checksum              on                     default
tank/Win10Root  compression           off                    default
tank/Win10Root  compressratio         1.00x                  -
tank/Win10Root  context               none                   default
tank/Win10Root  copies                1                      default
tank/Win10Root  creation              Sat Nov  4 14:21 2017  -
tank/Win10Root  dedup                 off                    default
tank/Win10Root  defcontext            none                   default
tank/Win10Root  fscontext             none                   default
tank/Win10Root  logbias               latency                default
tank/Win10Root  logicalreferenced     150G                   -
tank/Win10Root  logicalused           150G                   -
tank/Win10Root  mlslabel              none                   default
tank/Win10Root  primarycache          all                    default
tank/Win10Root  readonly              off                    default
tank/Win10Root  redundant_metadata    all                    default
tank/Win10Root  refcompressratio      1.00x                  -
tank/Win10Root  referenced            302G                   -
tank/Win10Root  refreservation        528G                   local
tank/Win10Root  reservation           none                   default
tank/Win10Root  rootcontext           none                   default
tank/Win10Root  secondarycache        all                    default
tank/Win10Root  snapdev               hidden                 default
tank/Win10Root  snapshot_count        none                   default
tank/Win10Root  snapshot_limit        none                   default
tank/Win10Root  sync                  standard               default
tank/Win10Root  type                  volume                 -
tank/Win10Root  used                  831G                   -
tank/Win10Root  usedbychildren        0                      -
tank/Win10Root  usedbydataset         302G                   -
tank/Win10Root  usedbyrefreservation  528G                   -
tank/Win10Root  usedbysnapshots       0                      -
tank/Win10Root  volblocksize          8K                     -
tank/Win10Root  volsize               512G                   local
tank/Win10Root  written               0                      -
```

Answer (score 1):

This is totally a case for checking the [man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=zfs&sektion=8) for ZFS:

> referenced
>
> The amount of data that is accessible by this dataset, which may or
>      may not be shared with other datasets in the pool. When a snapshot
>   or     clone is created, it initially references the same amount of
>   space as   the file system or snapshot it was created from, since its
>   contents   are identical.
>
> This property can also be referred to by its shortened column name,
>      refer.

and...

> logicalreferenced
>
> The amount of space that is "logically" accessible
>   by this dataset.   See the referenced property.  The logical space
>   ignores the effect of      the compression and copies properties, giving
>   a quantity closer to   the amount of data that applications see. 
>   However, it   does include     space consumed by metadata.
>
> This property can also be referred to by its shortened column name,
>      lrefer.

Things to consider:

- Were your zvols sparse?
- What were the compression and deduplication properties?
- What's inside of the zvol?

Comment: The man page is actually where I got the idea that `lrefer` should be higher than `refer`. I posted all of the zvol properties above, but the zvol is not sparse and both compression and deduplication are off. The first 150G of the zvol are a block-for-block copy of a 60% full Windows 10 OS drive.

Comment: Was the original Windows drive ever full or have 302GB used inside of it? You know that when files are deleted inside of a filesystem on top of a zvol, that space isn't reclaimed, right?

Comment: No, it is physically only a 160GB drive (drive maker's bytes). It was only about 110 full but when I copied it I copied the zeros as well.